# Export data from a database to a .csv file

Tags: php, sql, csv, joomla, export

I have a PHP file which exports data from a database to a csv file.

I want to add more fields from the database to export.

Original file:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');

class IeSimpleExport extends IeController{

function view(){
    $jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
    $ie_id = JRequest::getInt("ie_id");
    $_importexport = JTable::getInstance('ImportExport', 'jshop'); 
    $_importexport->load($ie_id);
    $name = $_importexport->get('name');
    $ie_params_str = $_importexport->get('params');
    $ie_params = parseParamsToArray($ie_params_str);

    $files = JFolder::files($jshopConfig->importexport_path.$_importexport->get('alias'), '.csv');    
    $count = count($files);

    JToolBarHelper::title(_JSHOP_EXPORT. ' "'.$name.'"', 'generic.png' ); 
    JToolBarHelper::custom("backtolistie", "back", 'browser.png', _JSHOP_BACK_TO.' "'._JSHOP_PANEL_IMPORT_EXPORT.'"', false );
    JToolBarHelper::spacer();
    JToolBarHelper::save("save", _JSHOP_EXPORT);                

    include(dirname(__FILE__)."/list_csv.php");  
}

function save(){
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();

    include_once(JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE."/lib/csv.io.class.php");

    $ie_id = JRequest::getInt("ie_id");
    if (!$ie_id) $ie_id = $this->get('ie_id');

    $_importexport = JTable::getInstance('ImportExport', 'jshop'); 
    $_importexport->load($ie_id);
    $alias = $_importexport->get('alias');
    $_importexport->set('endstart', time());        
    $params = JRequest::getVar("params");        
    if (is_array($params)){        
        $paramsstr = parseArrayToParams($params);
        $_importexport->set('params', $paramsstr);
    }                
    $_importexport->store();

    $ie_params_str = $_importexport->get('params');
    $ie_params = parseParamsToArray($ie_params_str);

    $jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
    $lang = JSFactory::getLang();
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = "SELECT values.name_en-GB as value, prod.product_id, prod.product_ean, prod.product_quantity, prod.product_date_added, prod.product_price, tax.tax_value as tax, prod.`".$lang->get('name')."` as name, prod.`".$lang->get('short_description')."` as short_description,  prod.`".$lang->get('description')."` as description, cat.`".$lang->get('name')."` as cat_name
              FROM `#__jshopping_products` AS prod
              LEFT JOIN `#__jshopping_products_to_categories` AS categ USING (product_id)
              LEFT JOIN `#__jshopping_categories` as cat on cat.category_id=categ.category_id
              LEFT JOIN `#__jshopping_taxes` AS tax ON tax.tax_id = prod.product_tax_id
              LEFT JOIN `#__jshopping_products_extra_field_values` AS values USING (name_en-GB)              
              GROUP BY prod.product_id";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $products = $db->loadObjectList();

    $data = array();
    $head = array("product_id","ean","qty","date","price","tax","category","name","short_description","description", "value");
    $data[] = $head;

    foreach($products as $prod){
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $prod->product_id;
        $row[] = $prod->product_ean;
        $row[] = $prod->product_quantity;
        $row[] = $prod->product_date_added;
        $row[] = $prod->product_price;        
        $row[] = $prod->tax;
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->value);
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->cat_name);
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->name);
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->short_description);
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->description);
        $data[] = $row; 
    }


    $filename = $jshopConfig->importexport_path.$alias."/".$ie_params['filename'].".csv";

    $csv = new csv();
    $csv->write($filename, $data);

    if (!JRequest::getInt("noredirect")){
        $mainframe->redirect("index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=importexport&task=view&ie_id=".$ie_id, _JSHOP_COMPLETED);
    }
}

function filedelete(){
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
    $jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
    $ie_id = JRequest::getInt("ie_id");
    $_importexport = JTable::getInstance('ImportExport', 'jshop'); 
    $_importexport->load($ie_id);
    $alias = $_importexport->get('alias');
    $file = JRequest::getVar("file");
    $filename = $jshopConfig->importexport_path.$alias."/".$file;
    @unlink($filename);
    $mainframe->redirect("index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=importexport&task=view&ie_id=".$ie_id);
}

}
?>
```

I need to export custom data from the table `jshopping_products_extra_field_values` and column name `name_en-GB`.

I modified the code, but after exporting, nothing exports except the first line with titles of the fields.

My code:

```
<?php
 defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');

class IeSimpleExport extends IeController{

function view(){
    $jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
    $ie_id = JRequest::getInt("ie_id");
    $_importexport = JTable::getInstance('ImportExport', 'jshop'); 
    $_importexport->load($ie_id);
    $name = $_importexport->get('name');
    $ie_params_str = $_importexport->get('params');
    $ie_params = parseParamsToArray($ie_params_str);

    $files = JFolder::files($jshopConfig->importexport_path.$_importexport->get('alias'), '.csv');    
    $count = count($files);

    JToolBarHelper::title(_JSHOP_EXPORT. ' "'.$name.'"', 'generic.png' ); 
    JToolBarHelper::custom("backtolistie", "back", 'browser.png', _JSHOP_BACK_TO.' "'._JSHOP_PANEL_IMPORT_EXPORT.'"', false );
    JToolBarHelper::spacer();
    JToolBarHelper::save("save", _JSHOP_EXPORT);                

    include(dirname(__FILE__)."/list_csv.php");  
}

function save(){
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();

    include_once(JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE."/lib/csv.io.class.php");

    $ie_id = JRequest::getInt("ie_id");
    if (!$ie_id) $ie_id = $this->get('ie_id');

    $_importexport = JTable::getInstance('ImportExport', 'jshop'); 
    $_importexport->load($ie_id);
    $alias = $_importexport->get('alias');
    $_importexport->set('endstart', time());        
    $params = JRequest::getVar("params");        
    if (is_array($params)){        
        $paramsstr = parseArrayToParams($params);
        $_importexport->set('params', $paramsstr);
    }                
    $_importexport->store();

    $ie_params_str = $_importexport->get('params');
    $ie_params = parseParamsToArray($ie_params_str);

    $jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
    $lang = JSFactory::getLang();
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = "SELECT values.name_en-GB as value, prod.product_id, prod.product_ean, prod.product_quantity, prod.product_date_added, prod.product_price, tax.tax_value as tax, prod.`".$lang->get('name')."` as name, prod.`".$lang->get('short_description')."` as short_description,  prod.`".$lang->get('description')."` as description, cat.`".$lang->get('name')."` as cat_name
              FROM `#__jshopping_products` AS prod
              LEFT JOIN `#__jshopping_products_to_categories` AS categ USING (product_id)
              LEFT JOIN `#__jshopping_categories` as cat on cat.category_id=categ.category_id
              LEFT JOIN `#__jshopping_taxes` AS tax ON tax.tax_id = prod.product_tax_id
              LEFT JOIN `#__jshopping_products_extra_field_values` AS values USING (name_en-GB)              
              GROUP BY prod.product_id";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $products = $db->loadObjectList();

    $data = array();
    $head = array("product_id","ean","qty","date","price","tax","category","name","short_description","description", "value");
    $data[] = $head;

    foreach($products as $prod){
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $prod->product_id;
        $row[] = $prod->product_ean;
        $row[] = $prod->product_quantity;
        $row[] = $prod->product_date_added;
        $row[] = $prod->product_price;        
        $row[] = $prod->tax;
        $row[] = $prod->value;
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->cat_name);
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->name);
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->short_description);
        $row[] = utf8_decode($prod->description);
        $data[] = $row; 
    }


    $filename = $jshopConfig->importexport_path.$alias."/".$ie_params['filename'].".csv";

    $csv = new csv();
    $csv->write($filename, $data);

    if (!JRequest::getInt("noredirect")){
        $mainframe->redirect("index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=importexport&task=view&ie_id=".$ie_id, _JSHOP_COMPLETED);
    }
}

function filedelete(){
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
    $jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
    $ie_id = JRequest::getInt("ie_id");
    $_importexport = JTable::getInstance('ImportExport', 'jshop'); 
    $_importexport->load($ie_id);
    $alias = $_importexport->get('alias');
    $file = JRequest::getVar("file");
    $filename = $jshopConfig->importexport_path.$alias."/".$file;
    @unlink($filename);
    $mainframe->redirect("index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=importexport&task=view&ie_id=".$ie_id);
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at the csv exporting done in com_banners (in the tracks view, toolbar)

Comment: this file belongs to joomshopping component

Comment: Yes so do the same thing but with that file I said look at it, not copy it line for line. If you follow the same basic concept as was done there you can do what you want.

Comment: Thanx, i will try and tell the result.

Comment: You did not mention the structure of your custom table jshopping_products_extra_field_values. In your SQL query you are using "USING" clause to join the custom table with the products table. So both tables should have the same column "name_en-GB" present otherwise your query will fail and csv file do not contain any data.

Comment: If any researchers are looking for a general-purpose module to export a result set as a .csv file, here is something that I recently cooked up: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/24285/12352